# KnockOutJS binding issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

i am using MVC4, jquery2.03 and knockout2.30 and i'm unable to see the total dependents.
Am i missing something here?

Model

```
namespace eManager.Domain
{
    public class Dependent
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<eManager.Domain.Dependent>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>Total: <span data-bind="text: dependent().length">&nbsp;</span> dependents(s)</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = {
        dependent: ko.observableArray(initialData)
    };

    $(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, but mixing server side rendering (Razor) and JavaScript is bad.

Comment: Check initialData. Chances are, it's not an array, or is an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from this jsFiddle, your knockout binding is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pdavis68/k9rG9/

This would mean the issue has to do with your initialData. Putting the Razor syntax in the script is very likely the problem. You could add a method to your controller that returns the data as a string and then use a `$.getJSON()` call to retrieve the data and then populate your view model (this is how our code operates).

For your controller, you could have something like:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetDependents()
{
    Dependent[] dependents = GetAllDependents();
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dependents);
}
```

then in your Javascript, something like:

```
$.getJSON("http://mysite.com/controller/GetDependents", function(data) {  
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
         viewModel.dependent.push(val);
     });
});
```

(This was all top of my head, so probably note precisely correct, but should get you close).

Comment: this is how the initalData appears when i view source

<script type="text/javascript">
    var initialData = [{"Id":0,"Name":"Tall Hat","Age":10},{"Id":0,"Name":"Long Cloak","Age":12}];
    var viewModel = {
        dependent: ko.observableArray(initialData)
    };

    $(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
</script>

Comment: In the document.ready add: `alert(initialData.length);` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 0):

In my controller have added the following

```
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetDependents()
    {
        var dependents = _db.Dependents;
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dependents);
    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<eManager.Domain.Dependent>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>Total: <span data-bind="text: dependent().length">&nbsp;</span> dependent(s)</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:1233/Dependent/GetDependents", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            viewModel.dependent.push(val);
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () { ko.applyBindings(viewModel); });
</script>
```

when i call http://abc.xyz/Dependent/GetDependents
i get the following response
[{"RelationshipManager":{},"Id":1,"Name":"Tall Hat","Age":10},{"RelationshipManager":{},"Id":2,"Name":"Long Cloak","Age":12}]

But still it is not showing the count